# Sobre input en python

Tags: python, input, float

mi pregunta es la siguiente, agrego imagen para simplificar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen de arriba, el input de la linea 4 se convierte a un input de numeros en la linea 8. Cabe resaltar que estoy apenas empezando a programar, sin embargo, cuando necesito un input de numeros, no los convierto si no que uso el `float(input(""))` . Mi pregunta es la siguiente, si en la linea 4 de la imagen anterior uso el `float(input(""))` en lugar de usar un input de strings, que deberia poner en la linea 8?

Gracias por leer y perdon si la pregunta parece muy obvia, apenas estoy aprendiendo y es algo que no se como solucionar, gracias :)

Comment: Por favor, los datos relevantes (mensajes de error, **código**) han de incluirse **como texto**. Las imágenes no se pueden copiar/pegar para hacer pruebas o buscar documentación.  Un saludo.

Comment: No entiendo, se más claro: ¿Que intentas hacer? ¿Obtiene algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Si pones en la linea 4:

```
sval = float(input("Enter a number"))
```

ya no tienes que poner `fval = float(sval)`, solo pondrias `fval = sval` porque ya viene convertido a float.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas float(input()) en la linea 4 el condicional if sval = 'done' no se cumpliría nunca y el bucle while se haría infinito (a no ser que lo cambies a otro valor de detención a otro valor como por ejemplo 0 o 99999999).

Si estás comenzando te sugiriría dejar de lado las excepciones hasta que tengas interiorizados los bucles y condicionales. Aún, así, ya que es una buena práctica, si quieres mantener el bloque de las excepciones yo especificaría qué tipo de excepción es (IOError) y movería el bloque de excepción al principio.

También tendrías que renombrar los nombres de las variables porque todas serían fval (tipo float).

```
num = 0
tot = 0.0
while True:
    try:
        fval = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    except IOError:
        print('Invalid input')
    if fval == 0:
        break
    num += 1
    tot += fval
```

Espero que te haya servido la respuesta y te animo a continuar, bienvenido a un mundo apasionante :)

Answer (score 0):

Al ser `input` una entrada por teclado que proviene del usuario, puede que exista la posibilidad de que no se pueda realizar la conversión a número (`float` en este caso).

El bloque `try` intenta realizar la conversión del `input` al tipo de dato `float`, pero en caso de que no sea posible se ejecuta el bloque `except`.

Una alternativa al código de la imagen sería incluir todo dentro del bloque try:

```
while True:
    try:
        fval = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
```